# Lock all fields in PDf by using Javascript

Tags: javascript

The following coding is working fine on desktop PC, Mac.  But it does not work on mobile devices as all fields are not locked after clicking the OK button.

```
var resp = app.alert("Are you sure to lock the contents?", 2, 2);
if (resp == 4)
  for (var i = 0; i < this.numFields; i++) {
    var f = this.getField(this.getNthFieldName(i));
    if (f == null) continue;
    f.readonly = true;
  };
```

I want its working on mobile devices such as Android, iPad and iPhone

Comment: Code you have provided is not sufficient as what is `app`, what will be `this`.

Comment: That coding is used in the button of Adobe Pro DC.